# Accessing single json value via Angular?

Tags: angularjs, json

my API returns this value:

```
{"id":1,"name":"Test"}
```

In Angular I did this call to retrieve that value:

```
$scope.supplier = Suppliers.query({supplierId: $routeParams.id});
```

But now in my template I do this:

```
{{supplier.name}}
```

Even `{{ supplier }}` does not give me anything.

but this is empty. Why is this the case?

Thanks!

Comment: share your service or more code that you have in controller, in your case it looks like a promise is not getting resolved, so that could be your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query function returns a [callback](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/), try this:

```
Suppliers.query({supplierId: $routeParams.id}, function(suppliers) => {
    $scope.supplier = suppliers[0];
});
```

Since query returns a list you need to take only the first from the list.

Comment: I had to do it a bit differently:

    Suppliers.query({supplierId: $routeParams.id}, function(response) {
       $scope.supplier = response;
    });

But in this case {{ supplier }} looks like this in the frontend: [{"id":1,"name":"Test"}] - so we have an array with an object, but supplier.name or supplier.0.name does not result in anything :( Any idea? I do not see it :(

Comment: Ah I can use {{supplier[0].name}}

Comment: Updated my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

var supplier = Suppliers.query({supplierId: $routeParams.id},{_id:0,name:1});

$scope.supplier=supplier[0].name;